# How to convert AT TIME ZONE return value to actual datetime value in SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to convert UTC value to Eastern Time Zone (any time zone) in SQL directly. I am trying below query but getting DATETIMEOFFSET.

I am trying to convert below UTC DateTime into Eastern time zone.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2019-05-27 13:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'
```

I am expecting output for above query is '2019-05-27 09:00:00' but the actual output is coming like '2019-05-27 13:00:00 -04:00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

```
 select CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2019-05-27 13:00:00'), DATEPART(TZOFFSET, 
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. So far, you've told SQL Server the native time zone for the datetime that you've passed in. *Now* you need to tell it to convert it to something else. This should do the trick:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'2019-05-27 13:00:00')
   AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time'
   AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

This should give you something with the `-00:00` offset. If you don't want that, cast the result back to a time zone-less datatype.